# Как освободить память сразу всем полям структуры?

Tags: c++, указатели

Здравствуйте.
Вот **пример** кода:

```
struct BUFF
{
    int * a;
    int * b;
    int * ...;
};

main() {
    BUFF buff;

    buff.a = new int[32];
    buff.b = new int[32];
    buff.... = new int[32];
    // какие-то действия ...

    // освобождение памяти
    delete[] buff.a;
    delete[] buff.b;
    delete[] buff.....;
}
```

Вопрос:

Есть ли способы удаления сразу всех полей структуры а не по одной строчки "**delete[] buff.**..."?

Comment: Нельзя. Сколько `new`, столько и `delete`.

Comment: Конструктор и деструктор...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для этих целей используйте умный указатель `std::unique_ptr`. Когда объект структуры прекратит свое существование, то автоматически будут вызваны деструкторы для его полей-указателей.

В процессе работы вы можете назначать новые значения для указателей с помощью функции-члена класса `reset`.

Например,

```
#include <memory>

//...

struct BUFF
{
    std::unique_ptr<int[], std::default_delete<int[]>> a;
    std::unique_ptr<int[], std::default_delete<int[]>> b;
    std::unique_ptr<int[], std::default_delete<int[]>> c;
};


BUFF buff = BUFF();

// ...

buff.a.reset(new int[32]);
buff.b.reset(new int[32]);
buff.c.reset(new int[32]);
```

Другой подход - это написать отдельную функцию-член структуры следующим образом

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <memory>

//...

struct BUFF
{
    int *a;
    int *b;
    int *c;
    void reset()
    {
        std::initializer_list<int *> l = { a, b, c };
        std::for_each(l.begin(), l.end(), std::default_delete<int[]>());
    }
};

//...

BUFF buff = BUFF();

//...

buff.reset();
```

Answer (score 1):

Не понимаю, кто мешает один раз написать конструктор и деструктор?

```
struct BUFF
{
    int * a;
    int * b;
    int * ...;
    BUFF():a(new int[32]),b(new int[32]),...{}
    ~BUFF(){ delete[]a; delete[] b; ... }
};

main() {
    BUFF buff;

    // какие-то действия ...

    // освобождение памяти - НИЧЕГО
}
```

Можно проявить особую хитро...сть :) и сделать так:

```
struct BUFF
{
    int * a;
    int * b;
    int * ...;
    BUFF():a(new int[128])
    {
        b = a + 32;
        ...
    }
    ~BUFF(){ delete[]a; }
};
```

В принципе, при большом количестве полей и частом создании и удалении `BUFF` может даже оказаться эффективным за счет резкого уменьшения обращения к диспетчеру памяти.